# JAVA store string Array in postgres and retrieve a JSON data from it

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I'm getting into trouble with images paths storage in DB.
If I pass a paths as string array and store it in text[] array column in PostgreSQL - I receiving a text value in response like

```
"item_id":44,"item_phone":"432432423423","item_price":67676,"item_descr":"iojgoewjgoiwejgiewjgojoij","item_images":"{8f8161d3a6bdf6ahrth8fd35725356.jpg,11136408_101535465482739704_1782611644_o.jpg,15032923164db54t54d7ee548.jpg.thumb.jpg}","item_title":"ojreogreoihIGJEI","item_email":"jfeiwojiejowegj@ijfe"
```

"item_images" array value is in " " in the response, so I receive it just as string value. But I want to receive it as JSON array/list

So, what is the better way to organize this images paths storage in DB to finally receive a data from it as a JSON list/array?

This is how it works now:

**The model to receive a data from Post:**

```
public class Item {
    public String title;
    public String descr;
    public String phone;
    public String email;
    public String images[];
    public int price;
}
```

This is how I **store a values in DB:**

```
    PreparedStatement statement=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO goods (item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_images, item_price)\n" +
            "                    VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");
    int index=1;
    statement.setInt(index++, item.condo_id);
    statement.setString(index++,item.title.trim());
    statement.setString(index++,item.descr.trim());
    statement.setString(index++,item.email.trim());
    statement.setString(index++,item.phone); //Assuming it is a String
    statement.setArray(index++, conn.createArrayOf("text", item.images));
    statement.setInt(index++,item.price); //Assuming it is a Double
    int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();
```

This is how I **return this values in the form of JSONArray**:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("query to select all data from DB");

        JSONArray jsonArray;
        jsonArray = convertToJSON(rs);

public static JSONArray convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        int total_rows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
            obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                    .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
        }
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify convertToJSON() method like this

```
            String name = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                    .toLowerCase();
            int type = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i);
            if (java.sql.Types.ARRAY == type) {
                obj.put(name, resultSet.getArray(i + 1));
            } else {
                obj.put(name, resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
            }
```

Comment: doesn't help, same output(

btw, should be `int type = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i+1);`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your problem that you are making images a string first?

public class Item {

```
public String title;
public String descr;
public String phone;
public String email;
public String images[]; 
***************** public Array images[];
public int price;
```

}

Comment: Don't think so.
Anyway i store it as Array successfully 

`  statement.setArray(index++, conn.createArrayOf("text", item.images));`